# Concavity changes

Tags: calculus

I'm done being confused by Galois theory and am back to being confused by elementary calculus.

I have a polynomial of degree $m-1$ that is bounded by the curve $y = x^m$ and intersects it at a nonzero number of points.  Does each of these intersection points represent a change in concavity (or two, given that it has to go down and up again)?  Also, am I right in saying there can be at most $m-3$ changes in concavity?  Thanks, I kind of forgot this stuff.

Comment: I believe the curve $2x^3 - 3x^2$ is bounded by $x^4$ and intersects it at the origin, but doesn't change concavity there.

Comment: ok, thanks!  i guess that settles it then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have a polynomial $y = p_{m-1}(x)$ and there exist some real solutions of $p_{m-1}(x) = x^m$.

A function $f(x)$ is concave at point $x$ if $f''(x)<0$ and convex if $f''(x)>0$. The change in concavity occurs when $f''(x)=0$.

If you are asking whether that implies that $p''_{m-1}(x)$ is zero at those points, than I think it does not. Consider example of $m=4$ and $p_3(x) = x^3-x+1$. The equation $p_3(x) = x^4$ admits two real solutions $x=\pm1$. The second derivative of the polynomial is $6x$ and is not zero at those points.

Comment: thanks...I fail at calculus :P

Comment: There was the condition "bounded by $\dots$"

Comment: oh wait...yeah I guess this is still an open question then, good call :)

Answer (score 0):

About the "also" part of the question:

It is clear that if $m < 3$ there are no changes in concavity.

Suppose that $m \ge  3$.  Your polynomial has degree $m-1$.  So its second derivative has degree $m-3$.

Everywhere that there is a change in concavity, the second derivative is $0$.  But a polynomial of degree $k$ has at most $k$ zeros.  So the function can change concavity at most $m-3$ times.

**Side Comment**: The $0$ polynomial does *not* have degree $0$, or at least not many mathematicians say that it does.  One convention is that it does not have a degree.  Another convention is that it has degree $-\infty$.  I have also seen $-1$ offered as the degree of the $0$ polynomial.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!